# Hydroponic nutrient solution filtration

Tags: diseases, watering, hydroponic, lettuce, resources

I am looking to build a small-scale hydroponic farm; lettuce/tomatoes/etc, and am now looking into a filtration system for my re-circulating reservoir. I have previously run into pathogen issues within my system in Florida, so for this up-scaled version, i would like to add some type of filtration to the nutrient solution, to kill off any bacteria/pathogen buildup.

After some research, i have found a few solutions:
UV Filtration
Slow filtration
Adding Ozone gas
Heat pasteurization
The list goes on...

I am curious, for a small scale ~5000 plant sites, coming from a ~500 gallon reservoir, what is the most efficient (time & cost) process.

I would assume slow filtration would be easiest to setup, and passive, however requires a decent amount of Maintenace.

Ozone & Uv seems fairly simple, plug & play, while heat pasteurization seems like a larger process to setup.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you could tell us where in the world you are from since ambient temperatures will sure impact upon any phytosanitary precautions. Have you any photos of your system and also an approximate length of the active hydroponic set up since all you have given us is the fact you intend to have a 5000 plant installation which would be well beyond that for home use, implying that you will be reselling the produce commercially. This may, depending upon your country or even region within that country, require official approval & certification, wherein free advice from experts is possible.